# How to reuse HTML/Controller for Add/Edit user in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two separate HTML templates for Add / Edit user and hence two separate controllers. **How i can have one HTML file and one controller for both Add/Edit functionality.**

**Add User**

```
  <div>
       <label>FirstName</label>
                    <div>
         <input type="text" name="name"  data-ng-model="register.Student.FirstName">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>LastName</label>
                    <div>
         <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="register.Student.LastName">
                    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit User**

```
  <div>
                    <label>FirstName</label>
                    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="student.Student.FirstName">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>LastName</label>
                    <div>
         <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="student.Student.LastName">
                    </div>
</div>
```

**AddController** which initialize FirstName and Last Name to null value. This is not the case in my EditController.

```
       $scope.register = {
                User: {
                    FirstName: '',
LastName: '',
            };
```

My route configuration

```
 templateUrl: '/app/users/newStudent.html',
        controller: 'newStudentController',
        controllerUrl: '/app/users/newStudentController.js', 

       templateUrl: '/app/users/editStudent.html',
        controller: 'editStudentController',
        controllerUrl: '/app/users/editStudentController.js',
```

Comment: Post your `EdiController` too.

Comment: Why would you need that? EditCotnrooler does not have logic what i mentioned above for AddController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Club both the `html` files and name it say `student.html` and club both the `controller` files and name it say `student.js`.

**student.js**

`app.module('myApp', []).controller('studentController', function () {})`

Your route config:

```
templateUrl: '/app/users/student.html',
        controller: 'studentController',
        controllerUrl: '/app/users/student.js',
```

### UPDATE

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/uh17tseh/1/**

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="stud in students">
        <div ng-hide="isEditForm">
            <span>{{stud.name}} - {{stud.age}}</span>
            <button ng-click="isEditForm=true;">Edit Student</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="isEditForm">
            <label>Enter Name</label><input ng-model="stud.name" />
            <label>Enter Age</label><input ng-model="stud.age" />
            <button ng-click="isEditForm=false;">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>

    <div ng-hide="isAddForm">
        <button ng-click="isAddForm=true;">Add Student</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="isAddForm">
        <label>Enter name</label><input ng-model="newStudent.name" />
        <label>Enter Age</label><input ng-model="newStudent.age" />
        <button ng-click="addStudent()">Add</button>
        <button ng-click="isAddForm=false;">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.students = [
        {"name": "ABC", "age": 21},
        {"name": "DEF", "age": 22},
        {"name": "GHI", "age": 23},
        {"name": "XYZ", "age": 24}
    ];
    $scope.newStudent = {};
    $scope.addStudent = function () {
        if ($scope.newStudent.name && $scope.newStudent.age) {
            $scope.students.push({"name": $scope.newStudent.name,"age": $scope.newStudent.age});
            $scope.isAddForm = false;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @softar, thanks.  2nd point. there is some logic specific to AddStudent and some logic specific to EditStudent. How can i keep that check in common controller?

Comment: Have two different functions for each, something like `$scope.AddStudent` and `$scope.EditStudent`. Use different variables for both the sections. If you can tell my the logic definitions more precisely, I can help you much better.

Comment: @softar, e.g.AddStudent.Html contains password field which should be hidden for EditStudent.html.. so combining both html files, how can i show/hide password field? 2nd in controller some code should only be executeable for AddStudent and not for EditController. please refer last section of my original question. waiting for your comments. thanks

Comment: See my update. Hope it answers all your question now. Feel free to ask your doubts else mark it as an answer so it won't appear to be unanswered.

Comment: @ softvar, thanks for your explanation. So for it looks what i am looking for. just in case i struck somewhere, i will ask you.

Comment: The code works well as expected, but for each students there created a edit form which makes the source code larger. How to reuse the one edit form for all students? Thanks